# Drawing line under view in android

Tags: android, view, line, android-canvas, z-order

I am using the onDispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) method to draw lines in my view.  When I call canvas.drawLine() it always draws the line on top of all my views.  Is there any way to draw the line under a button but on top of another view in my layout using canvas.drawLine()?

I have tried the following but it still draws the line over the button.

```
Button b;
RelativeLayout r;
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

     Paint p = new Paint();
     p.setColor(Color.Black);

     canvas.drawLine(0,0,100,100,p);

     r.removeView(b);
     r.addView(b);
}
```

Comment: Use RelativeLayout to meet your needs. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637690/how-to-position-a-custom-shape-inside-a-view/6719195#6719195

Comment: I am using a relative layout, I need to draw the lines at run time.

Comment: Draw the line then invalidate only the button. Dont add/remove..

Comment: I have tried both invalidate() and bringToFront() with no success.

Comment: Have you tried calling `super.dispatchDraw(canvas);` after drawing the line? Dont add/remove the button there..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to reinvent the wheel. Z-ordering is already implemented in the window management subsystem and you can use it.

1. Create a custom view you want to draw on.
2. Make it non-clickable using `android:clickable="false"` or `setClickable(false)`.
3. Make its background transparent and implement `dispatchDraw()`.
4. Put all the views you don't want to draw on above this view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I want the view to be clickable. I am trying to draw on top of a listview.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to draw a line over a listview and under a button. I want the listview to be the bottom layer, the line to be the middle layer, and the button to be the top layer.

Comment: Is button a part of the list's child views? And I think you'd better write it in your question.

Comment: The button is not a child of the listview.

Comment: So as far as I understand you have a `RelativeLayout` with overridden `dispatchDraw()`. This layout contains a `ListView` and a `Button`. And you want to draw something on the `LsitView` but under the button, don't you? And I can't understand why you can't just put some other view with overridden `dispatchDraw()` on the `RelativeLayout` between the `ListView` and the `Button`.

Comment: You are correct about what I am trying to do.  The reason I can't use a View that is 1 pixel wide is because sometimes it appears as two pixels wide and sometimes it appears as one pixel wide.  I am using pixels not density pixels, but I have tried both.

Comment: I mean you can use a view which will fill the parent `RelativeLayout` and it will be doing all the drawing your `RelativeLayout` does now. So you won't have to care about drawing above or below some views. You'll be able to put all the view in the order you want in xml.

Comment: So what you are saying is I can add a standard view and then draw on the view? If that is correct you have answered my question.

Comment: You can extend a `View` and override its `dispatchDraw()` method. In this method you can draw everything you want to draw. Then you can add this view to the `RelativeLayout` under the button. And that's all.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that before. Edit your answer if you would like the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want me to add to the answer? Comments just repeat my answer. And you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Call `super.dispatchDraw()` after drawing the line. The dispatchDraw is called by `viewgroup` for drawing its children, so in your case, calling `super.dispatchDraw()` will draw the button first then you are drawing the line over it. Do `dispatchDraw` this way :

### Updated code

```
class myListViewWithLine extends ListView {
....
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

         Paint p = new Paint();
         p.setColor(Color.Black);
         canvas.drawLine(0,0,100,100,p);

         super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
....
}
```

Comment: This code draws the line under the ListView.  I wanted the line to be positioned above the ListView, but below the Button.

Comment: Then override it in listview extended class. This is simpler and better than having multiple layered layouts. Do not fear to refactor your code because thats a part of the software lifecycle.  You'll have to improve it at some point.

Comment: Overriding ListView would work as well.  I re-factored my code as Pixie suggested and just overrode the View class. I placed my custom view on top of my ListView and under the button.  The lines were positioned appropriately on the z-axis and I was still able to click items on my ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Another method will be to just add a view with 1 dip as height and background color whatever you like under the button. It should look like like a line.

```
View v = new View(this);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);
v.setLayoutParams(lp);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

addView(v,INDEX NUMBER AFTER THE BUTTON);
```

Comment: The problem with this method is the entire layout is being re-drawn often.  Sometimes when it is re-drawn the views have different widths even though they are always set to 1 pixel.  I specifically need to use canvas.drawLine().

Comment: Add some more code like the layout. It will give everyone a bit more idea.